# trying to call non static function outside class in c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I'm working on a cryptocurrency exchange simulator that reads data from a CSV file and turns them into objects. I have a class called orderBook which does the reading. One of the class' functions is getKnownProducts, which prints all currencies as strings.

I want to call the function getKnownProducts from another function in the main cpp file to lists all products.

```
    class OrderBook
{
    public:
    /** Construct, reading a csv file*/
        OrderBook(std::string filename);
     /** Return vector of all known products in the dataset*/
        std::vector<std::string> getKnownProducts();
     //some more code...
};
```

I made an instance in the main file. (The constructor does read the CSV file but the code is omitted because it's irrelevant)

```
OrderBook orderBook{"20200601.csv"};
```

And this is the implementation in the cpp file.

```
std::vector<std::string> OrderBook::getKnownProducts()
{
    std::vector<std::string> products;

    std::map< std::string, bool> prodMap;

    //OrderBookEntry is a class that has a constructor with the data types required to store the data from the csv file.
    for(OrderBookEntry& e : orders) 
    {
        prodMap[e.product] = true;
    }
    // Flatten map to a vector of strings
    for(const auto& productStringBoolPair : prodMap)
    {
        products.push_back(productStringBoolPair.first);
    }
    return products;
}
```

Finally, I tried to call getKnownProducts from the following function when I got the typename error. vs code assumes I'm calling the function using the class but I'm doing so using an instance of the class. What should I do to make it clear?

```
void printProducts()
{
    for(std::string const& p : orderBook.getKnownProducts())
    {
        std::cout << "products: " << p << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect that to do? What is it supposed to mean to call a non-static method without an instance of the class? Where are you expecting values for the member variables (e.g. `orders`) magically to come from?

Comment: you need an object to call a member function. `OrderBook{"foo"}.getKnownProducts()` would be syntactically correct, but what you want to do is unclear

Comment: This is your problem: `OrderBook OrderBook{"20200601.csv"};` . Don't give the same name to your variables as you have given to the class. Do sth around `OrderBook ob("xxx");` and then `for (const auto& p : ob.getKnownProducts())` VTC as typo.

Answer (score 2):

A *class* is like a blueprint, it's there to create *instances* of that class type.

You can create *static* functions, which are just normal functions attached to the scope of that class, but any *method* needs an object of that class to be called:

```
class A
{
public:
static void classFunction(){}
void method(){}
};

int main()
{
    A::classFunction(); //That's ok, because it's a static function
    // A::method(); // Not ok, it needs an instance.
    A a; // Here we create an instance of class A
    a.method(); // That's ok, we have an instance.

}
```

In your case, `OrderBook` is a class name, so you can't call a method without an instance.

Comment: I do have an instance but it's in another file (does that matter?)

Comment: The instance has a scope, that is, the code which can access this object. You can access or pass object across files (note: file!=scope). 
Even through it's legal to use global variables, it's also a very bad practice.
So usually, you create an object where it matters and passes it to the required functions/methods.

Comment: Considering your last question edition: the instance can't have the exact same name than the class, this wont compile.

Comment: I made a typo here it's actually OrderBook orderBook{ }

Comment: I guess you can now pass it `const OrderBook& orderBook` to the `printProducts` function